# Como faço para mostrar alguns elementos de um array seguindo este critério?

Tags: php, array, formulário, checkbox, foreach

Tenho que fazer um formulário php que no final mostre o preço de cada produto comprado, mostrando apenas os preços dos produtos que na outra coluna da tabela, foram marcados no checkbox:

FORMULÁRIO:

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pag</title>
</head>
<style>
table{
    margin-top:10%;
    width:50%;
}
.comprar{
margin-left:49%;
}
#qtd{
        width:40px;
    }
.linha1{
    text-align:center;
}
.preco{
    width: 50px;
}
</style>
<body>
<form action="cupom.php" method="post" name="compras">
<table cellspacing="5" align='center' border='1'>
<tr class="linha1"><td>Produtos</td><td>Valor Unitário</td><td>Quantidade</td></tr>

<?php
$prod['Arroz']=1.2;
$prod['Macarrão']=2.6;
$prod['Biscoito Cream']=4.1;
$prod['Margarina']=4.89;
foreach($prod as $key => $value){
   ?>
   <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="produtos[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $key; ?></td>

   <td><input type="text" name="preco[]" class="preco" readonly value="<?php echo 'R$ '.$value; ?>"></td>

   <td><input type="number" name="qtd[]" id="qtd" min="0" max="100">
   </tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Comprar" class="comprar">
</form>
</body>
</html>**
```

NOTA FISCAL:

```
<?php
require "pag1.php";
$prod_comp = $_POST['produtos'];
$qtd_prod = $_POST['qtd'];
$precos = $_POST['preco'];
foreach($prod_comp as $value){
     echo '<p align="center">'.$value."</p>";
}
foreach($qtd_prod as $value){
     echo '<p align="center">'.$value."</p>";
}
foreach($precos as $key => $value){
     echo '<p align="center">'.$value."</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Não já esta sendo feito?

Comment: Mas ele mostra todos os preços no array de preços, ele deve mostrar apenas os preços dos produtos que foram comprados

Comment: qual é o campo que guardas que o produto ja foi comprado ?

Comment: fornece o código, onde marcas o produto como comprado.

Answer (score 0):

É importante de relembrar que numa submissão de formulário apenas são enviados os `<checkbox>` que estão marcados/selecionados, os que não estão nem sequer chegam a ser enviados. Se não for marcado nenhum essa chave nem existirá em `$_POST['produtos']`, logo isto:

```
foreach($prod_comp as $value){
     echo '<p align="center">'.$value."</p>";
}
foreach($qtd_prod as $value){
     echo '<p align="center">'.$value."</p>";
}
foreach($precos as $key => $value){
     echo '<p align="center">'.$value."</p>";
}
```

Não está correto pois assume que todos existem sempre e `$prod_comp` não existirá sempre e terá tamanho dependente do que foi selecionado. Para além disso o `$qtd_prod` e o `$precos` não dependem do que foi escolhido em `$prod_comp`.

Em vez disso podemos alterar o html da `<checkbox>` para ter um valor numérico sequencial:

```
$prod['Margarina']=4.89;
$num = 0; //numero do produto
foreach($prod as $key => $value){
   ?>
   <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="produtos[]" value="<?=$num++?>"><?php echo $key; ?></td>

   ...
<?php 
}
```

O que vai fazer com que o html gerado para as `<checkbox>` tenha o seguinte aspeto:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="produtos[]" value="0">Arroz</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="produtos[]" value="1">Macarrão</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="produtos[]" value="2">Biscoito Cream</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="produtos[]" value="3">Margarina</td>
```

Desta forma quando for submetido, pelo `value` sabemos quais as linhas que precisamos de ir ler aos outros arrays. Podemos então interpretar da seguinte forma:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){ //se foi submetido em post

    if (isset($_POST["produtos"])){ //se existem produtos escolhidos

        //criar os nomes num array
        $nomesProdutos = array('Arroz','Macarrão','Biscoito Cream','Margarina'); 

        //obter todos os arrays que vem de $_POST como já era feito
        $prod_comp = $_POST['produtos'];
        $qtd_prod = $_POST['qtd'];
        $precos = $_POST['preco'];

        echo "Produtos escolhidos:";

        //for apenas sobre os que foram escolhidos
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($prod_comp);++$i){
            $pos = $prod_comp[$i]; //obter a posição do elemento escolhido (0,1,2 ...)
            //ir buscar as informações aos outros arrays com base nessa posição
            echo "Nome:  $nomesProdutos[$pos]  Quantidade: $qtd_prod[$pos] Preço: $precos[$pos]<br>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Não escolheu nenhum produto";
    }
}
```

Esta solução já funciona para o objetivo pretendido. Uma solução mais organizada seria utilizar classes pois temos 3 arrays distintos que referem a mesma coisa, um produto. Por esse motivo podíamos criar uma classe `Produto` e criar objetos dessa classe dentro do `for`:

```
class Produto{
    var $nome;
    var $quantidade;
    var $preco;

    //construtor de Produto que recebe nome, quantidade e preço
    function __construct($nome, $quantidade, $preco){
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->quantidade = $quantidade;
        $this->preco = $preco;
    }
}


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if (isset($_POST["produtos"])){

        $nomesProdutos = array('Arroz','Macarrão','Biscoito Cream','Margarina');

        $prod_comp = $_POST['produtos'];
        $qtd_prod = $_POST['qtd'];
        $precos = $_POST['preco'];

        echo "Produtos escolhidos:";

        //Array de objetos produto
        $produtos = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($prod_comp);++$i){
            $pos = $prod_comp[$i];
            //acrescentar um novo objeto produto ao array
            $produtos[] = new Produto($nomesProdutos[$pos], $qtd_prod[$pos], $precos[$pos]);
        }

        //mostrar todos
        print_r($produtos);
    }
    else {
        echo "Não escolheu nenhum produto";
    }
}
```

Faria no entanto sentido criar um método especifico para poder mostrar o `Produto` no html de uma forma mais bonita e organizada, para que a visualização fosse idêntica ao código sem classes. Esse método poderia ficar assim:

```
class Produto{
    ...
    //método para obter o html do produto de forma mais organizada
    function obterHtml(){
        return "Nome:  {$this->nome}  Quantidade: {$this->quantidade} Preço: {$this->preco}<br>";
    }
}
```

E agora mostramos onde for necessário chamando apenas o método:

```
//mostrar todos
foreach ($produtos as $prod){
    echo ($prod->obterHtml());
}
```

Como nota adicional existe uma pequena falha no html que tem uma etiqueta de fecho `</td>` em falta em:

```
<td><input type="number" name="qtd[]" id="qtd" min="0" max="100">
   </tr>
```

Que deverá ser corrigida para

```
<td><input type="number" name="qtd[]" id="qtd" min="0" max="100"></td>
   </tr>
```